# How to attach the zipped folder names to all the files inside it in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder in a directory which has hundreds of zipped folders in it and also many files inside it.for example ,

**Folder**
   cs2-20150613-6014-0000-**201071**.zip
        cs2-20150613-abc.bin
        cs2-20150613-xyz.bin

cs2-20150614-6014-0000-**201066**.zip
        cs2-20150614-abc.bin
        cs2-20150614-xyz.bin

I want to attach the last 6 digits of the folder name to all the files after extracting,
        cs2-20150613-abc.bin-**201071**
        cs2-20150613-xyz.bin-**201071**

Can anyone suggest me how it can be done in **batch file**

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=1,2,5 delims=-." %%a in ('dir /B *.zip') do (
   ren %%a-%%b-*.bin %%a-%%b-*.bin.%%c
)
```

This code assume that the format shown is fixed: `cs2-YYYYMMDD-xxxx-xxxx-######.zip`. If this format may change, an adjustment in the code is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short script I wrote that should do what you need

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a in (*.zip) do (
    7z x -o"%temp%\%%~na" "%%a" > Nul <&2
    set "suffix=%%~na"
    set "suffix=!suffix:~-6!"
    for %%b in (%temp%\%%~na\*) do move /Y "%%b" "%cd%\%%~nxb-!suffix!" > Nul <&2
    rd /s /q "%temp%\%%~na" 
)
```

It requires that you have `7z` on your path for extracting the compressed files for `.zip` folders.

The suffix added it the extracted files is always the 6 characters before the extension for the `.zip` file, ignoring weather or not they're digits.

---

This code utilizes the idiom  `> Nul <&2` to redirect all output (`stdout` and `stderr`) to the `Nul` file, effectively silencing the program.

Comment: Thank you very much!! this is what i needed :) Can u pls tel me why is %%~fb and >Nul <&2  used for??

Comment: @Siri `> Nul <&2` is used to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` of a command to `Nul`. This means that the command no longer prints anything to the console. In retrospect, `%%~fb` doesn't do anything. It's the for variable expansion for the fully qualified path name but, in this case, the variable is already the fully qualified path name.

Comment: Thank u :) I have another requirement in this ,I want to extract zipped folders which are ending with only 77, i.e, ####77. Suppose the folder name is cs2-20150613-6014-0000-201077 ,I want files as cs2-20150613-abc.bin-201077 cs2-20150613-xyz.bin-201077 , am doing this like, set "suffix_77=!suffix:~4!" if !suffix_77! == 77 ( for %%b in (%temp%\%%~na*) do move /Y "%%b" "%cd%\%%~nxb-!suffix!" > Nul <&2 rd /s /q "%temp%\%%~na" ) but this is not working.

Comment: @Siri To only expand zipped folders whose names end in `77` you only need to change the second line of code to `for %%a in (*77.zip) do (`. In this context `*77.zip` will make the code execute only for files ending in `77.zip`

Comment: Ok..thanks v much ..Will this program extracts files and attaches last 6 digits if normal folders and files are are present inside the main folder..i.e                                                                                         **Folder**
cs2-20150613-6014-0000-201071
cs2-20150613-abc.bin
cs2-20150613-xyz.bin  **OR**                                                                                                                                               **Folder**
     cs2-20150613-abc.bin

Comment: don't help help vampires.